# centos 6.4 - django deploy with apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy on a VM with centos 6.4 a basic django project with apache and mod_wsgi. This is the project tree:

```
myproj/
├── manage.py
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── myproj
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

this is the wsgi.py file (it's the default generated by django-admin.py startproject):

```
"""
WSGI config for myproj project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""
import os

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproj.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

and this is the virtualhost configuration (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf):

```
#WSGIPythonPath /home/www/myproj/myproj
<VirtualHost *:82>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     WSGIScriptAlias /django /home/www/myproj/mypproj/wsgi.py
     WSGIDaemonProcess myproj user=apache threads=3
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
     </Directory>
     DocumentRoot /tmp
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

while i can access to index apache page (192.168.0.15:80 on my local network), if i try to point my broser on 192.168.0.15:82 i get "Destination unreachable". Any idea of what is missing or what is wrong in the configuration? 
on access or error log there's no trace of activity...

---

this is the modified virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     WSGIScriptAlias /django /home/www/myproj/myproj/wsgi.py
     WSGIDaemonProcess myproj user=apache threads=3 python-path=/home/www/myproj/myproj/:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup myproj
     <Directory /home/www/myproj/myproj>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
     </Directory>
     #DocumentRoot /tmp
     #ServerName www.example.com
     #ServerAlias www.example.com
     #Alias /media/ /home/www/myproj/
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

...nothing has changed. On:

```
wget 192.168.0.15:82
```

I get "Connection refused". The same configuration on a Debian machine works (in that case is mapped on port 80). Any help?

Comment: Unlreated, but you are missing a WSGIProcessGroup directive. Go read about what that does. Without it your application isn't going to run in that mod_wsgi daemon process group.

Comment: BTW, bad idea to set DocumentRoot to '/tmp' especially when you have your Django application hosted as a sub URL. If you managed elsewhere in your Apache configuration to say that Apache can serve up files from '/tmp' people could download files out of '/tmp' because of that DocumentRoot setting.

Comment: tnx. to summarize what is missing for have a working configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access port 82 directly, you'll need to open the appropriate port in the server's firewall. You can do this with the `system-config-firewall-tui` command line tool.

Comment: it has been deactivated as well